# Calling Angular controller function with ng-mousedown nested inside button in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, browser, angularjs-directive

I have a component that is a button used to open and close a dropdown element, and the option for the user to clear the selected items in the dropdown, when a ng-model value is present, as follows:

```
<button class="btn btn-default form-control" type="button" ng-click="ctrl.toggleDropdown($event)" ng-keydown="ctrl.onKeyboardPressed($event)" ng-mouseenter="icon=true" ng-mouseleave="icon=false">
        <span ng-if="ctrl.ngModel !== null" >
            {{ctrl.ngModelValue ? ctrl.ngModelValue : ctrl.placeholder}}
            <i class="removeSelectionIcon" ng-class="{'fa fa-close' : icon}" ng-mousedown="ctrl.clearSelection($event)"></i>
        </span>
</button>
```

To keep it brief, when a user clicks on the "fa fa-close" icon via ng-mousedown, I need to fire the function below:

```
 function clearSelection($event) {
        console.log("hey there");

        this.ngModel = null;
        this.ngModelValue = "";

        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

All works great in Chrome, but I'm not able to even get that console.log in IE and Firefox. When I click on the icon the dropdown is just open and closed as if I was clicking on the button itself. I've noticed if I double click fast on the icon I can clear the selected row but does anybody know what I need to do to get that mousedown event to fire when I click on the "fa fa-close" icon?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be due to nesting within the `<button>` element.  Using another element as the parent "button", such as `<div>`, produces the results you're looking for in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Here's a plunker demonstrating both.  https://plnkr.co/edit/wJ6OB7?p=preview

Generally speaking I think the real issue is that while you can nest HTML elements within a button (and not within `<input type="button">`) it is probably not a good idea to have elements acting as buttons nested in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Console.log is notorious for not working on certain browsers such as IE. It is always advisable to inject $log into your controller and use $log.info/$log.error/$log.debug instead of using console.log, because $log figures out how to log to console in each different browser.

I would also inject $scope into the controller and instead of defining the function in the manner you have above, do as follows:

$scope.clearSection = function(){}

And in the HTML, would use ng-mousedown="clearSection()"

Comment: Thanks...I can tell it's not getting called with or without the console.log because ngModel gets set to null, which clears the text of the button..so I know that function isn't getting called. I haven't had any issues with console.log. I'm just wondering if there is a different alternative for clicking the icon and getting the code I have to work in IE and Firefox

Comment: But don't you set ngModel to null inside the function clearSection?

Comment: yeah that's how I can tell the function is getting called or not. since its a button its actual ngModelValue which is getting set to an empty string. The code works I'm just looking for a solution in IE and Firefox

Comment: You might need to try adding a $scope.apply() in the function. This would allow for model changes to be reflected in the view